# Unescape and then sanitize data in Angular

Tags: angularjs, ngsanitize

The API I am using automatically escapes any strings from user inputs(as it should). I am having a real hard time finding the best way to unescape/sanitize the data to then use on my page. Is a directive a good route to go here?

**Sample Response**

```
&lt;b&gt;This is the response!&lt;/b&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;i&gt;It comes in italic, too.&lt;/i&gt;
```

**Template**

```
<div ng-bind-html="groupsDetailCtrl.group.information.text"></div>
<!-- Or pass in to directive? -->
<group-information content="groupsDetailCtrl.group.information.text"></group-information>
```

**Currently Output** on page is just something like this

```
<b>This is the response</b>
```

When of course it should be

**This is the response**

Comment: `ng-bind-html` also sanitizes so if you convert htmlentities first should be safe. Look for library to do conversion

Comment: have you included angular-sanitize.js?

Comment: @яша yes that is what I'm using for ng-bind-html.

Comment: @charlietfl Have any recommendations?

Comment: nope...should be easy to find htmlentity lib in google

Comment: @TheEks show me your controller please

Comment: @яша it's split between controllers and services

Comment: @TheEks are you getting the ngSanitze as a dependency in your module for instance  angular.module("your-module",['ngSanitize']);

Comment: @яша absolutely, yep. I think as Charlie was saying it's really the conversion/unescaping the entities that is the issue.

Comment: @charlietfl I know I'm killing you here, but I cannot find what I'm looking for. I've tried `Angular encode html entities` and `Angular encode html entities in response` and some other variations but I'm just not finding a solution.

Comment: just search `javascript htmlentities`... won't find anything angular specific. There is a library called php.js that might come across

Comment: @charlietfl exactly just decode the htmlentities and use them inside the ng-bind-html

Comment: Yep, thanks guys. For some reason I had been on the track originally that ngsanitize would handle both and got stuck on that.